# Where to find the http url scheme rfc

Tags: http, url, rfc3986

In the RFC3986, it exclude portions of RFC1738 that defined the specific syntax of individual URI schemes, and the document says the these portions will be updated as separate documents, But I can't find it. Any one can tell me where to find the updating separate documents. I want to write an HTTP URL scheme parsestrong text, so I need to refer it.

Answer (score 4):

You can look up the location of URI scheme definitions in the IANA URI scheme registry at http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html. Not surprisingly, the HTTP URI scheme is defined in RFC 2616 (which defines HTTP/1.1).

Comment: RFC 2616 has now been obsoleted by [RFC7230](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230).